# How to prevent the current window from losing focus when clicking a system tray icon

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, virtual-keyboard, topmost

I'm writing a C# Windows Forms app for Windows 10, similar to the system virtual keyboard. The app is topmost and it doesn't steal focus by overriding CreateParams and ShowWithoutActivation:

```
private const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;

protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams params = base.CreateParams;
        params.ExStyle |= WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
        return (params);
    }
}

protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation
{
    get { return true; }
}
```

The app can be minimized by the user to the system tray. This doesn't change the focus. However, when the app is restored from system tray (by clicking the app icon) the current active window loses focus.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior and keep the active window (before the mouse click) focused?

The app is minimized and restored using:

```
this.Hide();  // minimize on close event
..
this.Show();  // restore on notify icon click event
```

There was a similar question on here, but it's rather dated:
[Prevent system tray icon from stealing focus when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041532/prevent-system-tray-icon-from-stealing-focus-when-clicked)

Comment: Please give the code of your systray icon please and everything related to showing your keyboard. Also, do you know which window gets the focus when the active one loses it? If not, look into it as it might help solve the problem.

Comment: If you have focusable (non-windowless) controls on that Form, change them with something that cannot receive the focus. Or paint the canvas. Or use the ToolStrip controls.

Comment: @Olivier the tray icon has no associated code except the Hide() when the user closes the form and the Show() in the icon mouse click event handler when the user clicks on the tray icon. The window having the focus when the mouse is clicked belong to explorer.exe

Comment: @Jimi, the form does not gain the focus when restored from system tray but rather a window that belongs to explorer.exe. This kinda makes sense since if you click anywhere outside a focused window (e.g., blank area at the task bar) that window will lose focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a temporary solution until someone finds a proper one. It works by continuously reading and saving the window in focus inside the app's tray icon mouse move event.
This saved window will be set to focus inside the the tray icon mouse down event:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

private void notifyIcon_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (lastActiveWin != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(lastActiveWin);
    }
}

IntPtr lastActiveWin = IntPtr.Zero;
private void notifyIcon_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    lastActiveWin = GetForegroundWindow();
}
```